# Showing color swatches with price for each product

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9.1. I want to show the color swatches with price for each product.

I have tried lot of options but i didn't get solution. So any one guide me,how can i create color detail with price for each product on front page.

Comment: do you want to show color swatches on configurable products ?

Comment: i don't want use extension. i create new.phtml file for product.from this file i want to call  color detail

Comment: also how i can  show the available colors name .

Answer (score 0):

You can configure color swatches in magento1.9 versions

Here is the detail documentation for this:

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog|Swatches|_____0